# "attribute missing android namespace prefix" in official code snippet from Google doc. (about optimizing Android apps for ChromeOS)

Tags: android, android-studio, xml-attribute, androidappsonchromeos

I added this line to the manifest xml file of my app, according to documentation for optimizing for ChromeOS Android app publishing

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" required="false" />
```

but I get "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix..." for the "required" attribute.

If I add the Android: namespace prefix it works but I do not know if it is the right thing to do because I copied that line from the official web-page:

```
https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/index.html
```

and it has not the prefix.

It is right to add the prefix?

Comment: You need the android: prefix, it's a bug in the documentation. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Comment: I filed [a bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=647229) with the Chrome team to get this fixed.